# Check if Function exists on DB2 when overload exists

Tags: db2

Using Db2, I'm trying to have an "error proof" function to check if a given function/stored procedure exists, and if true, then drops it.
For non-overloaded functions it works fine, but if the same function exists with another signature but the same number of parms, the function will not work.

Example:

```
create function aaa.a_drop(in a integer, in b varchar(32)) 
returns integer 
begin 
return(1) 
end;
```

```
create function aaa.a_drop(in a varchar(32), in b integer)
returns integer 
begin 
return(1) 
end;
```

Those two functions have the same name and parameter count, but different signatures.

I'm using this code to check for the object and return `1` if it exists.

```
call aaa.drop_if_exists('aaa','a_drop',2,'integer,varchar(32)');
create function drop_if_exists(in v_schema varchar(128),in v_function_name varchar(128), in v_params_counter integer, in v_params_signature varchar(128) default null)
returns integer
begin
 declare v_count integer;--
 select count(1)
 into v_count
 from syscat.routines
 where ROUTINESCHEMA = v_schema
 and routinename = v_function_name
 and routinetype = 'f'
 and parm_count = v_params_counter
 return v_count;--
end;
```

This returns the two functions. I can give the signature in the function but I can't find the individual function in syscat.routineparms.

How can I verify that the function/stored procedure exists in Db2?

Comment: Is `create or replace function` syntax available in your Db2 version?  Would you consider using different specific-name per variant and use that in searching? Otherwise search additionally on syscat.routineparms per signature.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using different values for `PARMS` column.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT P.ROUTINESCHEMA, P.SPECIFICNAME, LISTAGG(P.TYPENAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY P.ORDINAL) AS PARMS
FROM SYSCAT.ROUTINES R
JOIN SYSCAT.ROUTINEPARMS P ON P.ROUTINESCHEMA = R.ROUTINESCHEMA AND P.SPECIFICNAME = R.SPECIFICNAME
WHERE P.ROWTYPE IN ('B', 'O', 'P')
AND R.ROUTINESCHEMA = 'SYSPROC' AND R.ROUTINENAME = 'SNAP_GET_DB'
GROUP BY P.ROUTINESCHEMA, P.SPECIFICNAME
)
WHERE PARMS = 
--'VARCHAR'
'VARCHAR,INTEGER'
;
```

There are 2 `SYSPROC.SNAP_GET_DB` functions in Db2 for LUW.
You may select the one needed passing the string enumerating its parameter types as in the example. Note, that there is no need to pass parameter length - you can't create 2 functions with the same parameter number, order and data type, but with different (var)char length.

Comment: thanks i adapted the code to my need, im using the result if the FN exists to run a sql command like `'DROP FUNCTION' || v_schema || '.' || v_function_name || ' ' || COALESCE(v_params_signature, '');` in the v_params_signature im passing only the parms without they size/lenght that triggers an error about varchar needing the size or (), there is some other way?

Comment: You may use `DROP SPECIFIC FUNCTION` with `ROUTINESCHEMA` and  `SPECIFICNAME` of `SYSCAT.ROUTINES` returned by my query. No need to use parameter list in the `DROP` statement in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the syntax `create or replace function` if it is available in your Db2-version.

You can also choose to give each overloaded-version a different `specific` name , and then search for that specific name in `syscat.routines` and use `drop specific function...`  syntax which can be useful.

Otherwise you can search in `syscat.routineparms` per argument per signature, although that seems more effort that using `create or replace` for such a simple thing.